# Calling generic method in spring.net application context

Tags: c#, generics, spring.net

I'm trying to invoke this method in spring.net, but i'm having trouble getting the configuration right.

Method:

```
public void AddRepository<TEntity>(IRepository<TEntity> repository)
   where TEntity : IEntity
{
   Repositories.Add(repository.GetType().Name, repository);
}
```

Config:

```
<object type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.MethodInvokingFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
    <property name="TargetObject">
      <ref local="RepositoryFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="TargetMethod" value="AddRepository"/>
    <property name="Arguments">
      <list>
        <ref object="BinaryAssetFileRepository"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>
```

Is it possible to address generic methods in this way?

Comment: In the meanwhile I found the problem.
The type parameter can be passed with the method name in the TargetMethod property:

<property name="TargetMethod" value="AddRepository&lt;Edu3.DTOModel.BinaryAsset.BinaryAssetExtensionDto>"/>

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> In the meanwhile I found the problem. The type parameter can be passed with the method name in the TargetMethod property:

```
<property name="TargetMethod" value="AddRepository&lt;Edu3.DTOModel.BinaryAsset.BinaryAssetExtensionDto>"/>
```

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))